# @Transactional is not rolling back db transaction

Tags: spring, sql-insert, jdbctemplate, rollback, transactional

I am trying to use @Transactional in one of my method. Scenario below:

**Scenario:**  I am copying 2 files from one folder to another folder and wanted to insert a record in table with file details such as **file_name**, **file_location**, etc.

**Approach:** Here I am inserting a record first and then actually moving the file. This method is annotated as `@Transactional`.

**Expected:** Now before moving the file I am checking, if, both file exists at source directory. If they don't exists at source then I am throwing `RuntimeException()` which should rollback the insert statement.

**Actual:** After exception is thrown insert entry is not getting rolled back.

```
@Transactional
private static void moveFilesAndUpdateDB(srcFile1, srcFile2, destinationDir) throws RuntimeException
{
    jdbcTemplate.update("insert into ......");
    Boolean sourceFileExists = sourceFilePresentCheck(srcFile1, srcFile2);
    if(sourceFileExists)
    {
        //code to dopy files
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

After throwing RuntimeException also, insert entry is not getting rolled back.

Comment: It could depend on multiple things. How do you call this? is the method of bean? Do you call the method from another method annotated with @Transactional? Do you intercept the exception?

Comment: You can't make private methods transactional, they can't be proxied.

Comment: @StanislavL I cal this method as a simple method call.. neither is the method of bran nor from other Transactional method. I intercept an exception in else clause as mentioned in above code by doing `throw new RuntimeException()`

Comment: `@Transactional` on `private` methods doesn't work. `@Transactional` on `static` methods doesn't work. You are doing both...

Comment: Yeah.. I removed `private` and `static` now

Answer (score 1):

In your case `@Transactional` is just ignored. Instead transaction was opened somewhere above in the method calling this one.

`@Transactional` works on Spring beans and on `public` non `static` method. When bean is created Spring creates a proxy where transaction opening/commit/rollback logic is evaluated.

To fix:

1. Make the class a Bean
2. Make the method non `static` and `public`
3. Check calling method transaction. To ignore it add propagation `REQUIRES_NEW` to let a new separate transaction be opened.

Comment: Thanks for your help @StanislavL.. can you please tell me what exactly I need to do to make the class Bean? Which class I should convert into Bean.. I am very new to spring framework.. So unable to understand.. requesting you to bit explain the same.. help is appreciated.. Thanks much!

Comment: The class which contains the moveFilesAndUpdateDB method. It's too broad to explain. It's better to read how Spring works and how Transactional works in spring.

Comment: sure StanislavL.. any reference links about the code I need to do will also help me.. if you have please share

Comment: I think there is no just one single example or link. It's better to google because I don't know good resource for beginners. Moreover looking for libraries or tutorials are offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, you also need to add (rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class) after @Transactional.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
private static void moveFilesAndUpdateDB(srcFile1, srcFile2, destinationDir) throws RuntimeException
{
  jdbcTemplate.update("insert into ......");
  Boolean sourceFileExists = sourceFilePresentCheck(srcFile1, srcFile2);
  if(sourceFileExists)
  {
    //code to dopy files
  }
  else
  {
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```